# gpg2 -- get fingerprint using script

Tags: gpg

I am attempting to extract the fingerprint from a GPG2 key. The fingerprint will then be passed to `pass init $GPG2_FINGERPRINT` for initialization

In the example below I want the fingerprint value `0126E6FFD15E33B8BCE7B748E79142F98581FC60`.

```bsh
$ gpg2 --list-signatures
pub   rsa2048 2021-10-14 [SCEA]
      0126E6FFD15E33B8BCE7B748E79142F98581FC60
uid           [ unknown] User 1 (User 1) <user@1.com>
sig 3        E79142F98581FC60 2021-10-14  User 1 (User 1) <user@1.com>
sub   rsa2048 2021-10-14 [SEA]
sig          E79142F98581FC60 2021-10-14  User 1 (User 1) <user@1.com>
```

When using `--with-colons` the subkey fingerprint is also returned. How can I get a clean output without the subkey info?

if I omit `--list-keys` and use `--with-fingerprint` instead I get pretty close... expect the warning is displayed: `gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean`. I can redirect the warning to get a clean output but I would rather use the correct command

Is there another way I can accomplish this? The end goal is to setup `pass` with a GPG key via scripting (no user interaction).

```bsh
$ gpg2 --with-fingerprint --with-colons ./pubring.kbx
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub:-:2048:1:E79142F98581FC60:1634220843:::-:
fpr:::::::::0126E6FFD15E33B8BCE7B748E79142F98581FC60:
uid:::::::::User 1 (User 1) <user@1.com>:
sub:-:2048:1:213A9C4C15D3AAA9:1634220843::::
```

Answer (score 3):

> When using `--with-colons` the subkey fingerprint is also returned.

The option `--with-colons` is the correct choice as it emits output in machine parseable format.

> How can I get a clean output without the subkey info?

I suggest piping it into `awk`. The output of `--with-colons` is standardized with each line having a data type in field 1. Any line with a data type of `pub` indicates the public key (as opposed to subkey) and the line that follows (data type `fpr`) contains the fingerprint string in field 10.

From this it becomes simple to parse the output with `awk` by scanning for the line(s) that begin with "pub:" and processing the fingerprint in field 10 from the line that follows.

For example, this will print all public key fingerprints on the keyring:

`gpg --with-colons -k | awk -F: '/^pub:.*/ { getline; print $10}'`

Comment: Technically, `/^pub:.*/` is no different than `/^pub:/`, but that's a minor issue.